# How would you translate "coming out" into Russian?

Tags: перевод, сленг

I'm working with a website related to homosexuality and coming out and I need to translate the concept of "coming out of the closet" into Russian. Multitran suggest выйти из тени, публично заявить (аналогия со шкафом, потому что дети прячутся в шкафу, когда играют в прятки - предложено иностранцем-знакомым TaylorZodi), but I'm not so convinced. So, how would you translate "coming out," both with and without the part "of the closet"?

Comment: Maybe it worth noting that one of most famous Russian LGBT organizations bear the name _‘Выход’_, which obviously is a translation of _Coming out_ as a noun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no specific term or expression for this in Russian, so you can consider three options:

- use plain common words and simple narrative: "он признал, что он
  гей", "он заявил о своей нетрадиционной ориентации", "он перестал скрывать, что он гомосексуал".
- translate the English expression. This is becoming common in the media, but
  always demands additional explanation: "как говорят на Западе, он "вышел из шкафа", т.е. заявил о своей гомосексуальности" or "Красовский, как теперь говорят, совершил камин-аут — в прямом эфире сказал, что он гей". It sounds a little awkward, like many other words and expressions Russian is trying to adopt at the moment ("smoothie" becomes "смусси" and sounds just plain weird), but it is spreading quite fast.
- try to invent a new expression. "Раскрыть карты" or "выйти на свет" that were suggested here are by no means accepted expressions to talk  about homosexuality, but "to come out of the closet" wasn't once either. If you do that, however, you risk sounding corny.

Comment: smoothie is usually adapted as смузи, and the latter is incredibly popular.

Answer (score 6):

У этого узко специфического термина в той среде и в том информационном контексте, в котором он употребляется, уже довольно прочно сформировалась традиция не переводить этот термин и употреблять его как есть: `каминг аут` или `каминг-аут`. Чаще всего употребляется вместе с глаголами действий вроде `сделать`, `совершить`.

===

De-facto this term does not translate and is used "as is", transliterated as `каминг аут` or `каминг-аут`. This is a noun, which is typically used with action verbs, such as `сделать` (to make) or `совершить` (to commit). Also, as far as I know, the term `выйти из шкафа` is also pretty understandable in the Russian gay community.

**ps:**
Here are some examples of using this terms by "native speakers": ))) http://www.afisha.ru/article/gay-issue/

Answer (score 1):

There is no common and well accepted term for this in modern Russian. This means that variants are possible. Any of the following will work:

- открыться
- признаться
- заявить о себе

Comment: Would one need to contextualize these usages? i.e., would you need to say, "that is, he said he was gay."

Comment: If you just say `открыться` without any context, this has nothing to do with homosexuality. Full statement would be `Он признался, что он гей`.

Answer (score 0):

- открыться
- выйти на свет (из тени)
- признаться
- раскрыть карты
- заявить о себе

As others have noted, these expressions do not point directly to a 'coming out', only in the sense of "confess"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate on the usage, if they are commonly used in everyday speech, just the media, etc.

Comment: confess - это покаяться, а признаться и открыться - это всё ж таки не покаяться. Это признаться и открыться.

Comment: @shabunc please feel free to change word 'confess' to other, more suitable for "признаться и открыться".